# PowerShell: Is there a way to access Shell: Drive?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, explorer

is there a way to access the Shell: drive (That shell: Drive http://merabheja.com/open-folders-using-shell-commands/) in powershell or vbs to read his content. something like Get-Childitem Shell:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the [Start-Process](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135261) cmdlet to invoke these. 
Example:

```
Start-Process "shell:AccountPictures"
```

If you need to enumerate them, you can query the registry:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\FolderDescriptions
```

However, you are probably looking for some special folders, maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
 [Environment+SpecialFolder]::GetNames([Environment+SpecialFolder])
```

This will list you all available special folders. If you want to get the Path of one of these, use `GetFolderPath`:

```
[System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::CommonPictures)
```

Comment: Hi, Jisaak, what i need is a way to access and read the content of those folders with PowerShell, something like Get-childitem Shell:

Comment: `Shell:` includes more folders than `SpecialFolder` (which is mostly a enum for the `User Shell Folders`-paths), but he may be lucky and find what he needs. :-)